# Setting process.env variables with grunt-env results in undefined

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have this `grunt-env` task:

```
env: {
    dev: {
        NODE_ENV: 'dev',
        DEST: '<%= config.dev %>'
    },
    dist: {
        NODE_ENV: 'dist',
        DEST: '<%= config.dist %>'
    }
},
```

Along with a simply task to test that `process.env.DEST` is getting set correctly.

```
grunt.registerTask('testEnv', function(){
  console.log(process.env.DEST);
});
```

When I run it I get the expected output of `dev`.

```
Running "env:dev" (env) task

Running "testEnv" task
dev

Done, without errors.
```

Now if I use `process.env.DEST` inside another grunt task I get the value as `undefined`.

```
Running tasks: env:dev, testEnv, concat:preload

Running "env:dev" (env) task
Verifying property env.dev exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: (none)

Running "testEnv" task
dev

Running "concat:preload" (concat) task
Verifying property concat.preload exists in config...OK
Files: app/scripts/preload/modernizr.js -> undefined/scripts/preload.js
Options: separator="\n", banner="", footer="", stripBanners=false, process=false, sourceMap=false, sourceMapName=undefined, sourceMapStyle="embed"
Reading app/scripts/preload/modernizr.js...OK
Writing undefined/scripts/preload.js...OK
File undefined/scripts/preload.js created.

Done, without errors.
```

You can see the undefined in this line `Files: app/scripts/preload/modernizr.js -> undefined/scripts/preload.js`. It's a simple concat task where I want the output to be different dependent on the environment I set.

```
concat: {
    baseDir: '<%= config.app %>/scripts',
    preload: {
        src: ['<%= concat.baseDir %>/preload/*.js'],
        dest: process.env.DEST + '/scripts/preload.js'
    },
    libs: {
        src: ['<%= concat.baseDir %>/libs/*.js'],
        dest: process.env.DEST + '/scripts/vendors.js'
    }
},
```

I've been at this for a day now and have no clue what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.